# node.js роутинг без фреймворков

Tags: node.js, роутинг

В процессе освоения *node.js* по урокам в сети, столкнулся с таким явлением, как маршрутизация.

Я её сути не понимаю, а объясняют её везде на примере фреймворка *Express*, что только добавляет сложности.

Установил в свою заготовку приложения модуль `router` через *npm*, пошёл читать ридми, а там: *Router does one thing and one thing only - route http requests.*

Юмор я оценил, а как разобраться, не понял.
Прошу ткнуть в годный урок по роутингу без фреймворков. Чтобы не просто "как", но и "зачем". Желательно на русском, но там уж как получится.

Ну, или вдруг не лень кому коротко и красноречиво описать, как вообще используется роутер.

Вообще приму любую инфу по голой ноде.

Comment: Routing в смысле "обработка http-запросов" — всего-навсего установка обработчиков для нужных вам путей. Т.е. просто процедура, которую нужно выполнить, если на сервер https://ru.stackoverflow.com пришёл запрос по пути /questions/748410 , например. Обычно в этом случае сервер отправляет в ответ HTML-документ, но вообще реакция сервера может быть произвольной.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я так понимаю, речь про [эту](https://github.com/mafintosh/router) либу.

> Прошу ткнуть в годный урок по роутингу без фреймворков.

Так эта библиотека работает без всяких фреймворков, поверх стандартного `http`.

> Ну, или вдруг не лень кому коротко и красноречиво описать, как вообще
>   используется роутер.

Вы можете и без него обойтись:

```
const http = require('http');

const srv = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
     var uri = req.url; // вот тут у вас лежит теперь url, по которому пользователь обратился
});

srv.listen(8080);
```

Собственно всё, теперь вы можете обрабатывать `uri` как душе угодно.

Если использовать роутер:

```
route.get('/', function(req, res) {
    // этот метод сработает, если пользователь открыл корень сайта
});

route.get('/{x}x{y}', function(req, res) {
   // если пользователь открыл your_site/200x200, сработает этот метод
   // в req.params будет {x:'200', y:'200'}
});
```

[Здесь](https://github.com/mafintosh/router/blob/master/index.js#L74) происходит добавление правил для роутера. При поступлении запроса от пользователя роутер сверяет запрос со списком правил, который вы ему дали и вызывает необходимый колбек с вашей логикой.

Роутер просто упрощает работу. Нет необходимости самим парсить запрос и т.п.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что для каждого конкретного случая мы создаём в коллбэке сервера отдельную конструкцию вроде этого?
`route.get('/', function(req, res) {
    // этот метод сработает, если пользователь открыл корень сайта
});`

Comment: @AleksandrShemetillo можно группировать. Можно регулярные выражения использовать, чтоб не на каждый path создавать маршрут.

Comment: Спасибо, наладил первое подобие роутинга с вашей помощью.